# custom filter in custom arrayadaper by icon

Tags: android, filtering, android-arrayadapter

I have custom ArrayAdapter:

```
     public class CallAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CallItem> implements Filterable{
        View view;
        ContactHolder holder = null;
       int color = 0;
       Context context; 
       int layoutResourceId;    
       public static int rowHeight = 0;
        private ViewSwitcher switcher;
        List<CallItem> contacts = null;
        Map<ContactItem, View> contactViewMap = ContactsViewMapSingletone.getInstance().getOrderViewMap();
        private ArrayList<CallItem> filtredContacts;
        private Filter filter;
       public CallAdapter(Context context,  int layoutResourceId,List<CallItem> contacts) {
           super(context, layoutResourceId, contacts);
           this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
           this.context = context;
           this.contacts = contacts;
           this.filtredContacts = new ArrayList<CallItem>();
           this.filtredContacts.addAll(contacts);
       }
       @Override
       public CallItem getItem(int arg0) {
           return contacts.get(arg0);
       }

       @Override
       public long getItemId(int arg0) {
           return arg0;
       }
       /**  *   метод для привязки элементов UI к данным конкретного контакта */
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View row = convertView;
           view = row;
           if(row == null)
           {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call_item, parent, false);
               holder = new ContactHolder();
               holder.contactIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.contactIcon);
               holder.contactName = (CustomTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
               holder.contactNumber = (CustomTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.contactNumber);
               holder.contactDays = (CustomTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.contactDays);
               row.setTag(holder);
           }
           else
           {
               holder = (ContactHolder)row.getTag();
           }

           CallItem contact = contacts.get(position);
           try
           {

                holder.contactIcon.setBackgroundResource(contact.getIcon());
                holder.contactName.setText(contact.getName());
                holder.contactNumber.setText(contact.getDays());
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
                    e.printStackTrace();
           }


           return row;
       }
       @Override
       public Filter getFilter()
       {
           if (filter == null)
               filter = new CallFilter();

           return filter;
       }
       static class ContactHolder
       {
        ImageView contactIcon;
        CustomTextView contactName;
        CustomTextView contactNumber;
        CustomTextView contactDays;
       }
  @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    private class CallFilter extends Filter
       {
               @Override
               protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
               {   

                   Log.i(" filtered value", constraint.toString());
                   FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                   String prefix = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                   if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0)
                   {
                       results.values = contacts;
                       results.count = contacts.size();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       final ArrayList<CallItem> list =  new ArrayList<CallItem>();
                       synchronized (this)
                       {
                           list.addAll(contacts);
                       }
                       filtredContacts.clear();
                       int count = list.size();
                       for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
                       {
                           final CallItem pkmn = list.get(i);
                           if(pkmn.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(constraint))
                           {
                               Log.i("found pref",pkmn.toString() );
                               filtredContacts.add(pkmn);
                           }
                       }
                       Log.i("prefix",prefix);
                       for(int i = 0, l = filtredContacts.size(); i < l; i++)
                       {
                           Log.i("filtered list",filtredContacts.get(i).toString());
                       }
                       results.values = filtredContacts;
                       results.count = filtredContacts.size();
                   }
                   return results;
               }

               @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
               @Override
               protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                   filtredContacts = (ArrayList<CallItem>)results.values;
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                   clear();
                   for(int i = 0, l = filtredContacts.size(); i < l; i++)
                   {  

                       add(filtredContacts.get(i));

                   }
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
           }

    }

    }
```

but I need to filter items not by name, but by icon. So user chooses icon by which items should be filtered and see list of items with those, which have this icon on the top. I tried to implement this (pass int as parameter) in the `performFiltering` but it have to get `CharSequence` parameter. And I need to implement this feature not on typing the value in EditText as usual, but get icon int in another Activity and return to my list and see items filtered. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it not by using custom Filter, but implementing probably not so elegant, but workable solution. When I return to my Fragment with int value by which adapter should be filtered, I do like this:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
         {
               if (requestCode==1)
             { 
                 if(resultCode == 0)
                 {
                     adapter.clear();
                     ArrayList<CallItem> filtered = new ArrayList<CallItem>();
                    int a=0;
                    for (CallItem call : adapter.getItems())
                    {
                        if (call.getIcon() == R.drawable.incoming_call)
                        {   
                            Log.i("item to filter", call.toString());
                            adapter.insert(call, a);
                            a++;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            filtered.add(call);
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.addAll(filtered);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                 }
                 else if (resultCode==1)
                 {
                     adapter.clear();
                     ArrayList<CallItem> filtered = new ArrayList<CallItem>();
                    int a=0;
                    for (CallItem call : adapter.getItems())
                    {
                        if (call.getIcon() == R.drawable.outgoing_call)
                        {   
                            Log.i("item to filter", call.toString());
                            adapter.insert(call, a);
                            a++;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            filtered.add(call);
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.addAll(filtered);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
                 else if(resultCode==2)
                 {
                     adapter = new CallAdapter(getActivity(),
                               R.layout.call_item, faq.getDisplayCalls(getActivity()));
                    contancts_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                 }
             }
}
```

as I mentioned, maybe it not so elegant, but workable for me. Hope it will be useful for somebody.